# cpu usage per process with bash script

Tags: cpu-usage

im trying to write a bash script to read the cpu usage per process.
but, i think im doing it wrong. when i test this script, it gives me an incorrect percentage.
heres the code:

```
prev_total=0
prev_idle=0
prev_processtotal=0
prev_utime=0
while true; do
cpu=`cat /proc/stat | head -n1 | sed 's/cpu  //'`
user=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $1}'`
system=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $2}'`
nice=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $3}'`
idle=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $4}'`
wait=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $5}'`
irq=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $6}'`
srq=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $7}'`
zero=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $8}'`
total=$(($user+$system+$nice+$idle+$wait+$irq+$srq+$zero))
diff_idle=$(($idle-$prev_idle))
diff_total=$(($total-$prev_total))
usage=$(($((1000*$(($diff_total-$diff_idle))/$diff_total+5))/10))
process=`cat /proc/20966/stat`
utime=`echo $process | awk '{print $14}'`
stime=`echo $process | awk '{print $15}'`
cutime=`echo $process | awk '{print $16}'`
cstime=`echo $process | awk '{print $17}'`
processtotal=$(($utime+$stime+$cutime+$cstime))
diff_processtotal=$(($processtotal-$prev_processtotal))
diff_utime=$(($utime-$prev_utime))
processusage=$(($((1000*$(($diff_processtotal-$diff_utime))/$diff_processtotal+5))/10))
clear
echo "total cpu usage: $usage%"
echo "one selected process: $processusage%"
prev_total=$total
prev_idle=$idle
prev_processtotal=$processtotal
prev_utime=$utime
sleep 1
done
```

im kinda lost here, so any help would be very much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prev_total=0
prev_idle=0
prev_processtotal=0
prev_utime=0
while true; do
cpu=`cat /proc/stat | head -n1 | sed 's/cpu  //'`
user=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $1}'`
system=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $2}'`
nice=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $3}'`
idle=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $4}'`
wait=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $5}'`
irq=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $6}'`
srq=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $7}'`
zero=`echo $cpu | awk '{print $8}'`
total=$(($user+$system+$nice+$idle+$wait+$irq+$srq+$zero))
diff_idle=$(($idle-$prev_idle))
diff_total=$(($total-$prev_total))
usage=$(($((1000*$(($diff_total-$diff_idle))/$diff_total+5))/10))
process=`cat /proc/19240/stat`
utime=`echo $process | awk '{print $14}'`
stime=`echo $process | awk '{print $15}'`
cutime=`echo $process | awk '{print $16}'`
cstime=`echo $process | awk '{print $17}'`
processtotal=$(($utime+$stime+$cutime+$cstime))
diff_processtotal=$(($processtotal-$prev_processtotal))
diff_utime=$(($utime-$prev_utime))
processusage=$(($((1000*$(($diff_processtotal***4**))/$diff_total+5))/10))
clear
echo "total cpu usage: $usage%"
echo "one selected process: $processusage%"
prev_total=$total
prev_idle=$idle
prev_processtotal=$processtotal
prev_utime=$utime
sleep 1
done
```

i have a quad core and it turned out that i had to multiply the value by 4 too...
now problem solved;)